# Nest Js, How can I apply a web socket adapter on onModuleInit?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, nest

Can I inject `INestApplication` into a module?

I want to access the app instance inside `onModuleInit` to use a web socket adapter

I thought I could get the app instance using `HttpAdapterHost`

```
    const httpAdapter = this.adapterHost.httpAdapter;
    const instance = httpAdapter.getInstance();
```

the instance object here does not have `useWebSocketAdapter` method
So How can I apply a web socket adapter on `onModuleInit`?

Currently, I apply the adapter on the `main.ts` file:

```
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
    rawBody: true,
  });

  const sessionStore = app.get(SessionStore);
  const wsAdapter = new WebSocketsAdapter(sessionStore, app);

  app.useWebSocketAdapter(wsAdapter);
```